# Mocha test returning different answer when compared to js bin

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing a function to try and remove the `<noscript>` tag from a string of html.

I've written my function below:

```js
function removeNoScript(str){
    var start = str.search("<noscript>");
    var end = str.search("</noscript>") + "</noscript>".length;

    var result = str.replace(str.substring(start,end),"");
    return result;
}

let result = removeNoScript("<p>first word</p><noscript>This shows up</noscript><p>second word</p>");

console.log(result)
```

This works perfectly fine, however when I run the a unit test on this with chai and mocha (below):

```
it("removes <noscript> in-between markup", () => {
    removeScripts(
      "<p>first word</p><noscript>This shows up</noscript><p>second word</p>"
    ).should.equal("<p>first word</p><p>second word</p>");
  });
```

I receive this result:
[image]

The same function works in JSBin went I log out the response - any idea why it works on JSBin but Mocha/Chai is returning an error?

P.S: In case it helps, this is a snapshot of the code I wrote in the editor (Ignore the comment about `<script>` because I plan to remove that next):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the tests. In the image you posted, you have:

```js
result = str.replace(str.substr(start, end),"");
```

Using `substr` instead of `substring`. The second argument of `substr` means the number of characters to extract, while the second argument of `substring` is the index of the first character to exclude.

substr: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

substring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Since `substr` is legacy you'll likely want to stick with `substring`.

Comment: Ha! Thanks for catching that. Noting to self not to get stuck in a rabbit hole on a Friday evening..